# sshd - Block login via ssh (sshd) for a certain period of time

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I use CentOS 7 and would like to know if it is possible to block login via ssh (sshd) for a certain period of time after a certain amount of attempts.

EXAMPLE: After 3 wrong attempts the login is blocked for 15 minutes.

**Thanks! =D**

Comment: I have no experience with this, but it looks like it may be available out of the box: https://www.tecmint.com/use-pam_tally2-to-lock-and-unlock-ssh-failed-login-attempts/.

Comment: Worth a look at `fail2ban`, see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-centos-7, this would mean you can block *all* incoming ssh for a period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment above said, `fail2ban` should be worth looking at. It prevents bruteforce attempts and supports whitelisting, so it should fit to your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `sshguard`, it will monitor the `sshd` logs and add an `iptables` rule to block connections from the ip address trying to log in for a set interval.

https://www.sshguard.net/